Calculating Sample Size for Cumulative Link Mixed Model (CLMM)
I am going to collect data in which each participant answers to 3 questions to 18 vignettes (each vignette has 3 questions), each question with likert scales 1-5. The dependent variables (questions) are "accomodation", "assimilation" and "immunization".
The 18 vignettes represent different combinations of manipulations: there are 3 with the following levels:
emotion: confusion, annoyance or neutral
importance: high or low
prior history: positive, negative, none.
I want to calculate the sample size I need for this experiment, but I can't find out how to do it, since my dependent variables are ordinal and every explanation about sample size calculation is for either binomial or continuous data.
So far, I planned to use mixed models and saw that CLMM would be good for ordinal data, but I don't know how to perform a sample size calculation given I am using CLMM.
